# How to write URL in Sharepoint List Send Email workflow?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

Below image shows 2 URLs. The first one will direct you to the current list item. Can you please help me with the second one? This URL should direct you to the site wherein all items in Pending Approval will be shown.

[image]

Comment: still need help?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a list view is in order. Create a list view where filters include: [Column] = pending and [approver] = [Me]

You'll then have a list view that will be filtered by the person who's logged in ([Me]) and all items that have a status of pending. Not sure what the column names are so I've made them up.

Here's a blog post that might help you set up your view: https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/sharepoint-library-views-and-list-views/

Once you have that list view, copy that URL and then send people to this view from your workflow email.

Hope that helps.